# java.lang.LinkageError when loading class from .zip file

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a class loader that will load .class files inside a .zip file. I followed this tutorial (https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/07/25/how-load-classes-jar-or-zip), but when i run the program, i get this error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of org/freeforums/geforce/genforcer/main/ZipClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "test/TestClass"
```

The error comes from line 30, which is:

```
return defineClass(filename, out.toByteArray, 0, out.size());
```

I call the method by using:

```
zipClassLoaderObj.findClass("test.TestClass");
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is that class already on the classpath?

Comment: Sorry, i'm brand new to using ClassLoader's and other semi-advanced features. Could you explain what that means?

Comment: What I'm asking has nothing to do with classloaders or much else. I'm asking if when you run the program the class is *already* on the classpath, loaded, etc.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's loaded. I added the line from which the error originates from to the main post.

Comment: *Subclasses of LinkageError indicate that a class has some dependency on another class; however, the latter class has incompatibly changed after the compilation of the former class.*  Although it's something of a "garbage" error.  I suspect in this case you get it because you've already loaded a version of test/TestClass.

Comment: @HotLicks In fairness, the error states explicitly what the problem is, and the OP backs this up.

Comment: @DaveNewton Do you know how i could fix this?

Comment: @Geforce132 http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html#dynamicreloading You might want to read the other in the series, they're pretty helpful if you're playing these types of games.

Comment: I think the solution is to simply not load test/TestClass anywhere else.  And this means you must not *reference* it anywhere else (the name "test.TestClass" must never appear anywhere outside of quotes), but must only access it using findLoadedClass/newInstance and superclass or interface definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I was calling the method two times because it was in a 'for' loop with a bunch of other code. Just took it out of the loop, and now it works perfectly. Don't know why i couldn't figure that out myself. Thanks for the help!